# how can I show an image in map pin annotation?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

i have one view >> subview mkmapview .

in that i want to show image . ...my current image is like this.[image]

and i want to show like this

[image]

how can i do this ? how can i add image in this anotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your MKAnnotationView set the leftCalloutAccessoryView property

> leftCalloutAccessoryView The view to display on the left side of the
>   standard callout bubble.
>
> @property (retain, nonatomic) UIView
>   *leftCalloutAccessoryView Discussion The default value of this property is
>   nil. The left callout view is
>   typically used to display information
>   about the annotation or to link to
>   custom information provided by your
>   application. The height of your view
>   should be 32 pixels or less.
>
> If the view you specify is also a
>   descendant of the UIControl class, you
>   can use the map view’s delegate to
>   receive notifications when your
>   control is tapped. If it does not
>   descend from UIControl, your view is
>   responsible for handling any touch
>   events within its bounds.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 3.0 and
>   later. See Also   @property
>   canShowCallout Related Sample Code
>   MapCallouts Declared In
>   MKAnnotationView.h

Apple [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/leftCalloutAccessoryView)

Answer (score 7):

The image you're talking about corresponds to the leftCalloutAccessoryView property of MKAnnotationView.

Extract from the doc :

> leftCalloutAccessoryView The view to
>   display on the left side of the
>   standard callout bubble.

You can implement a methods such as this :

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation {

    MKAnnotationView* annotationView = nil;

    MyAnnotation *myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation*) annotation;
    NSString* identifier = @"Pin";
    MKPinAnnotationView* annView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(nil == annView) {
        annView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftIconImage.png"]];
    annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Hope this helps,
Vincent

Comment: Last line should change to 'return annView;' instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
v.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]];
```

where v - is the view of your annotation(MKAnnotationView)
Or if you want complete solution - here it is:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    NSString *Identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f%f",annotation.coordinate.latitude,annotation.coordinate.longitude];
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView= (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:Identifier];
    if (annView==nil) {
        annView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:Identifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    RightCalloutAccessoryBtn* rightButton = [RightCalloutAccessoryBtn buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    annView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"]] autorelease];
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    return annView;
}
```

You should write this code on the class of your map's delegate

Comment: You are assigning a `UIImage*` to a `UIView*` property. I don't think that's going to work. Try `[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:...]`.

Comment: Adding a ```UIImage*``` to ```UIView*``` won't work. Try ```UIImageView*``` instead.

Comment: Of course, UIImageView, you are right guys. It was just mistake and this answer is so old I forgot about it (almost 5 years and even with manual reference counting code). Fixed my answer according to your comments