# Map annotation pin with using photo

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm confused with annotation's image view.

I've tried this:

[how can I show an image in map pin annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759947/how-can-i-show-image-in-map-pin-anotaton)

My map view can do what's shown in the first picture in that question.
Now I'm trying to do what's shown in the second picture.

Here is the question:

When I'm taking a photo, my map view will also create a pin with photo I've just taken.

How can get it?

I want let leftCalloutAccessoryView load image from iphone's camera library.

Here's my code for viewForAnnotation:

```
static NSString *identifier = @"MyLocation";
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MPViewPlaceMark class]]) {

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView =
    (MKPinAnnotationView *)[MapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (annotationView == nil) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                          initWithAnnotation:annotation
                          reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeftIconImage.png"]];
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

    annotationView.enabled = YES;
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;


    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: What have you done or tried so far?  Have you implemented the viewForAnnotation delegate method?  Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: The question you linked to is answered. Have you tried that answer?

Comment: Sorry for that! Now I'm fetch up the code. I tried the solution from the link I posted, but I want load the image from my iphone. Thanks for help!